# Easy way for a user to resubmit a webform

Tags: webform-civicrm

My users are clicking on an emailed link from CiviCRM to complete a webform, which when completed and submitted adds contacts to CiviCRM. I'd like them to be able to have an easy way of submitting the webform again without having to go back to the email, find the link and start over. This is because they are submitting details of one household per webform, and may have (say) 6 household they want to submit. I'm thinking that after submission they simply go back to the start of the webform - the problem is that to do that I'd need the url they clicked on, which has a couple of contact parameters in it. I can't find that in the tokens that are available, unfortunately. (moved from Drupal Answers)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a checksum from civimail, then I believe we have managed to 'daisy-chain' forms by enabling the checksum field and contact ID on form 1, and then use those as tokens in the path used after the submission so that info is passed through to form2 etc

EDIT I see my memory was slightly incorrect. Rather than putting the tokens in the Redirection field, we put them in an email and sent that to the person so they could jump to the next form eg

/node/xx?cid1=[submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_fieldset_fieldset:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_contact_id:nolabel]&cs1=[submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_fieldset_fieldset:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_cs:nolabel]

Comment: I inserted the tokens in the custom URL but they didn't get substituted. Looks like there's a patch in webform for this at https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3021818 but it applies to Drupal 8.  I'm on Drupal 7 (sad face)

Comment: I used "No redirect (reload current page)" after submit which worked, and included the parameters from the email.  So when the user clicks 'Submit' the webform starts again. It would have been nice to give them an option to start again or quit, but this works.  Thanks for putting me on the right tracks!

Comment: Andy - added an edit - i remembered where we were doing this in D7, and yes, we had to do it via sending them a link in an email to get around it